# Internet Explorer does not recognize iframe source

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer

I have a web application that if opened in Google Chrome or in Firefox works fine but in IE it does not work. The problem is when I try to change the src of an iframe. Here is the source of the iframe:

```
<iframe id="myFrame" name="I1" src="" style="border: thick inset #0000FF; width: 719px; height: 700px"></iframe>
```

The src, I change it when it loads the page (with the tag body onload)

This is the code that I have in the script to change the src:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function cargarImg() {
            var src1 = '<%= Request.QueryString["cobo"] %>';
            var src2 = '<%= Request.QueryString["carp"] %>';enter code here
            document.getElementById('myFrame').src = '////192.168.1.230/Pictures/TempFiles/' + src2 + '/cubo.swf';
        }
    </script>
```

Can someone tell me where the problem is? As I said, it works in Chrome or in Firefox but not in Internet explorer. Thank you

Comment: You have an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: what is  the version of ie where is does not work?

Comment: is not work in ie 8 and up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue is with setting the `src` using the `'////192.168.1.230/Pictures/TempFiles/'` path it is going up a directory from where your current page is instead of to the root.  Try replacing the string with this `http://192.168.1.230/Pictures/TempFiles/`.

Comment: Jonathan thanks that is the problem, I replace the string it is works in IE. Thanks.